# How 'try_files' directive of nginx thinks which resource should take?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, nginx, flask, gunicorn

## Background

I am building web app using nginx/gunicorn/Flask on EC2 (AWS). It seems good but I still have a question. I explain step-by-step so I want advice or comments !

## Environment

- EC2 instance on AWS
- Python v3.10.10
- nginx v1.22.1
- gunicorn v21.2.0
- Flask v2.3.2

Virtual environment is created for Python, whose name is "venv". It is located at "/home/ec2-user/venv"

## Settings

nginx.conf(some part is omitted.) @ /etc/nginx

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 1;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events{
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http{
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    server{
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;  <------ dummy domain name !
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        location / {
            try_files $uri @flask;
        }
        location @flask {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        }
    }
}
```

Following process is applied to restart nginx.

```
sudo systemctl stop nginx
sudo systemctl start nginx
```

In the root directory ("/usr/share/nginx/html"), there is an 'index.html'.

flask_app.py @ /home/ec2-user/python.source

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hellow World\n"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

wsgi.py @ /home/ec2-user/python.source

```
from flask_app import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

flask.service @ /etc/systemd/system

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve Flask
After=network.target
[Service]
User=ec2-user
Group=ec2-user
WorkingDirectory=/home/ec2-user/python.source
Environment="PATH=/home/ec2-user/venv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/ec2-user/venv/bin/gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:80 wsgi:app
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

'flask.service' is activated as following steps:

```
sudo systemctl start flask
sudo systemctl enable flask
```

## Result and my question

Here when I accessed the following uri:http://example.com/

> Hello World

is shown. My understanding for the directive 'try_files' is that nginx try to find matching resource from left side. In this situation, firstly $uri is considered and then there is an 'index.html' at root directory. But in fact, "Hello World" string is shown,  which means the 'try_files' directive could not find static resource so flask_app.py is launched instead. What do I think this order ? Why 'index.html' was not loaded ?

Comment: sudo systemctl status nginx,show output?

Comment: The `$uri` term will match files, but not directories. To find `index.html` using `http://example.com/` you need to use `try_files $uri $uri/ @flask;` - see [this documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Richard. So when I access the example.com, nginx recognizes the access is "/", not file, so that @flask is applied. Is it correct ?

Comment: Another question is that in the 'location' directive whose location is "/", resource is $uri or @flask. In this situation, when I want to access to  "http://example.com/resource/aaa.csv", which is a file, do I have to set another location like "/resource/" ?

Comment: In your current `try_files` statement, any URI ending with `/` will take the `@flask` action. If `/resource/aaa.csv` is located at `/usr/share/nginx/html/resource/aaa.csv` then your existing `root`, `location / {}` and `try_files` statements should return the requested file. You do not need to specify a `location /resource/` block unless you need to override something.